# Nasa's Orion program doesn't make sense

Tags: nasa, orion-spacecraft

Couldn't we launch the orion capsule on a launch system that is already developed? It makes no sense tp me that we would spend another half a decade just to build that vehicle. It doesn't make sense , and it's a waste of taxpayer dollars. If we really wanted to go to the moon we could do so in under two years. We have the tech , and we have the ability to manufacture.

I think nasa is foolishly wasting money. It's a half hearted attempt and it would've been best if they hadn't made an attempt at all.

Comment: A more appropriate version of this question for the Stack Exchange community would be "Are there better alternatives to NASA's Orion program?"

Comment: This question is a thinly veiled rant.  As such, I've voted to close.

Comment: @GreenMatt: Agreed, despite two good answers. Vote to close.

Answer (score 4):

Delta IV has the capability to put Orion into LEO, but not to take it to the moon, and that doesn't include the (as yet unbuilt) lunar lander module.

It's not clear to me what you're thinking of when you say "If we really wanted to go to the moon we could do so in under two years. We have the tech , and we have the ability to manufacture." If you mean Saturn V, then no; we may have the plans on paper but we don't have the tooling or the knowledge of the people who actually built them in the 1960s; a number of industrial procedures that were acceptable in the context of that time probably aren't so today.

SpaceX's stuff is definitely exciting and I wouldn't be surprised to see them dominate over the long term, but if your goal is manned landing on the moon, SLS can in principle do it with a single launch, rather than the two or three you'd need with Falcon Heavy.

Comment: Of course we don't have the tooling, and we can't use all their techniques, and we don't have the individuals that were there , but we do have the plans and we can create build a more advanced version of saturn v based on those plans. Of course we're not going to use the same materials , and the same techniques , but simply having the plans to a rocket that can get us to the moon AND having the plans to build the facilities to produce these parts , would be a big leg up. We're not going to build a replica , we're going to build a more advanced rough copy.

Comment: Building a more advanced Saturn V is a lot like building an SLS.

Comment: If the delta IV has the power to get the orion capsule moving at 18 000 mph, then why isn't that enough to get something to the moon?

Comment: @lululemon - Measuring things in terms of Δv makes it look oh so easy. A better metric is energy. Then it's not oh so easy. The rocket equation is a [tyrannical beast](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/expeditions/expedition30/tryanny.html).

Comment: According to Google, 18000 miles per hour is 8.05 km/s. That's approximately low Earth orbit velocity. To go to the moon (at least the way they did with Apollo) you need to go about 11 km/s ([Apollo 11's translunar orbit was about 35k ft/s](http://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029/Apollo_18-24_Translunar_Injection.htm), or 10.7 km/s). The difference between 8.05 km/s and 10.7 km/s is, in a few words, freakishly huge. Like @DavidHammen points out, the rocket equation is not your friend here.

Answer (score 1):

At some levels, the simple answer is that SLS (Space or Senate Launch System) is a jobs program and not about a space program.

It does not really make a whole heck of a lot of sense.

What is the justification for SLS?  Well to launch Orion in Lunar, Mars, or BEO mode, we need a booster bigger than the biggest available (Delta 4-Heavy, until Falcon Heavy is in operation).

Ok, so where is Orion going?  Dunno.  What is the mission?  Not sure.  How often do you plan to launch? Every 2-4 years if we are lucky, since there are no real missions, nor money to fund them, who knows.

It is somewhat ludicrous.

If you care about space, follow SpaceX and hope they succeed in reusability in Falcon 9 and Falcon Heavy and watch SLS get cancelled. If they succeed with the BFR and MCT model (Big F-ing Rocket, and Mars Colonial Transport fleet) then watch NASA fade to irrelevance due to mostly political shenanigans.

Comment: I am following space X and i think what elon is doing is brilliant. So much of the cost in the space industry is because of the difficulty in retrieving rockets intact. Once he has the technology perfected then the entire industry will change.